How to use a backup key with CertificatePinner Retrofit
 val certificatePinner: CertificatePinner = CertificatePinner.Builder()
        .add(
            certificateBase,
            certificateSHA
        ).build()
    builder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)

In Android we can add a backup key for public key pinning in Network Security Config File, I'm trying to add a Backup Key with CertificatePinner using Retrofit.
